# In React, can you use useState variable_1 as default value for another useState variable_2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1. Can you use useState variable_1 as default value for another useState variable_2, especially when variable_1 is being set by useEffect?
2. Even simpler, can you use useState variable_1 as default value for another useState variable_2 (without the useEffect dependency)?

To elaborate, here's an example

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("DEFAULT_NAME");
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState(firstName); //is doing this permissible?

useEffect(() => {
  setFirstName("REAL_NAME")
}, []);

console.log(fullName); // what would be printed here?
```

What would the value of `fullName` be? Would it be set to `"DEFAULT_NAME"` (signaling that it was set BEFORE the useEffect was called) or be set to `"REAL_NAME"` (signaling that it was set AFTER the useEffect was called)?

Comment: Eh,  3 console.logs maybe. Default, default and real. Why just test it, whats the problem on testing it

Comment: I think the primary purpose of the question was to figure out exactly when useEffect is called and how that's structured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components with hooks it's just a function, it executes from top to bottom; useEffect won't fires when React is ready to update it's view, it doesn't interfere with the useState initialization.

So you can do that, there's no problem. But, as @CertainPerformance mentioned at the end, it's better to just separate the defaultValue on a separate variable.

BTW, on this line:

```
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState(firstName);
```

`fullName` is going to be `"DEFAULT_NAME"` based on your example.
and here as well:

```
console.log(fullName); // what would be printed here?
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can*, but it usually wouldn't be a good idea. What'll happen is the second variable will be initialized to be the same as the first, but after that, they'll be completely disconnected from each other; updating either of the states later would not result in the other state changing.

Usually, in a situation where you might be thinking about something like this, it'd be better to have only a *single* state, with the dependent value calculated inside component (perhaps with `useMemo` for efficiency's sake), eg

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("DEFAULT_FIRST_NAME");
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("DEFAULT_LAST_NAME");
const fullName = useMemo(() => firstName + ' ' + lastName, [firstName, lastName]);
```

You don't want to do, eg

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("DEFAULT_FIRST_NAME");
const [capitalizedName, setCapitalizedName] = useState(firstName);
// ...
  onChange=(e => {
    setFirstName(e.target.value);
    setCapitalizedName(e.target.value.toUpperCase());
  })
```

It's messy to have state data duplicated in more than one state variable, and it can be confusing - you don't want to call a couple of state setters when updating only a single value.

But if the logic you're looking for doesn't require that - if you really only care to *initialize* both states to the same thing on mount, and have them be completely separate afterwards - then what you're doing now would be just fine.

Though, I'd consider it to be a bit clearer if both default values referenced the same outer variable:

```
const defaultName = "DEFAULT_NAME";
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(defaultName);
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState(defaultName);
```

That has less chance of confusing readers.

Comment: This explanation was helpful, thanks!